# Historical Data Modeling

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-modeling, adventureworks

In AdventureWorks2008R2 the Sales.SalesPerson table contains a TerritoryID which creates an easy reference to the current Territory assigned to a SalesPerson.  The Sales.SalesTerritoryHistory table is also available to analyze past assignments.

I noticed the HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory follows a similar pattern; however, the HumanResources.Employee table does not have a direct reference to the current Department.  In other words, there is no DepartmentID on the HumanResources.Employee table.

Is there a good reason why they wouldn't follow the same pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely the employee can work in multiple departments at the same time and that's why it is set up that way

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  It's too bad the data doesn't have at least one example of an Employee working in multiple departments or shifts at the same time.